# Working with a list in TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

[Here's the tutorial I'm working from](http://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B4BgTwf_ng_TM2MxZjJjZjctMTQ0OS00YzcwLWE5N2QtMDI0YzE4NGUwZDM3).

He has an example, `tupleReplicate`, which returns a function that takes a value and replicates it:

```
tupleReplicate :: Int -> Q Exp
tupleReplicate n = do id <- newName "x"
                      return $ LamE (VarP id)
                                    (TupE $ replicate n $ VarE id)
```

So `VarE id` returns an expression that can then be used with `replicate`? My question is, how would this work if `id` was a list? I want to do something like:

```
let vals = mkName "vals"
LamE (ListP vals) (map reverse $ ListE vals)
```

except that doesn't work because `ListE` returns `Exp`, not `[Exp]`.

More generally I want to write a function that takes a list and applies a function to it, in TemplateHaskell.

---

There's some example code [here](http://hpaste.org/86942), and I'm trying to write a function like

```
makeModel (id_ : name_ : []) = Person (fromSql id_) (fromSql name_)
```

Comment: `vals` is a list, reverse it?

Comment: Oops, I should've specified, `vals` is a `Name`, not a list.

Comment: How come? `ListE` accepts `[Exp]`.

Comment: None of this code works. `ListP` expects a `[Pat]` but is being given a `Name`. `ListE` expects a `[Exp]` but is being given a `Name`.

Comment: What do you want the generated function to look like?

Comment: `tupleReplicate 3` expands to `\x -> (x,x,x)`. For your list, what do you want your TH to expand to?

Comment: @AndrewC: `myFunc (v:vals) = (someFunc v) $ (myFunc vals)`

Comment: Sorry didn't read the entire post carefully the first time around :( It is not clear what do you want to achieve. You are making an abstract syntactic entity (a name) and you want to apply a list function to it (what is it supposed to do?) and get another abstract syntactic entity back (which one?)

Comment: I'm converting database rows to objects. So I get a database row back as a list: `[SqlValue]`. Now I want to convert this to an object. `MyObject` takes 6 values, and there are 6 items in my list. So I want to write a function in TemplateHaskell that, given this list, will return an instance of `MyObject`.

Comment: It doesn't look like you need any of TemplateHaskell. TemplateHaskell transform Haskell(ish) program fragments into Haskell program fragments. You are talking about converting a value into another value, neither of which are Haskell program fragments. If you do have a program fragment to transform, please show one.

Comment: @n.m. Do you know how to do this in TemplateHaskell: yes or no? Amazingly, sometimes I start projects in Haskell just to learn new things. Call me an idiot.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out *what* you want to do. Of course I don't know how to do that if I don't know what that *is*.

Comment: @n.m.: See here: http://hpaste.org/86942

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are trying to use a wrong screwdriver on this nail.

Comment: Oh I think I got it. Are you trying to generate code like `where makeModel [id, name] = Person (fromSql id) (fromSql name)` ?

Comment: Yes, that looks right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's turn on some extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
```

Now I'll fake some data types and classes to keep the interaction with the Real World low:

```
data Person = Person Int String deriving Show

class SQL a where 
  fromSql :: String -> a

instance SQL Int where fromSql = read
instance SQL String where fromSql = id -- This is why I needed FlexibleInstances
```

OK, now we need to decide what code we want to generate. Sticking closely to your example, we could define makeModel as a lambda expression (translation underneath):

```
LamE [ListP [VarP id,VarP name]] (AppE (AppE (ConE Person) (AppE (VarE fromSql) (VarE id))) (AppE (VarE fromSql) (VarE name)))
\       [         id,     name ] -> (    (         Person     (        fromSql        id ))   (         fromSql        name ))
\       [         id,     name ] ->                Person $            fromSql        id   $            fromSql        name
```

(I don't speak fluent `Exp`, I did `runQ [| \[id,name] -> Person (fromSql id) (fromSql name) |]` in ghci!)

I've chosen to use strings do define the identifiers `id` and `name`, because you could read that from the table, but you could just as well generate identifiers called `field_1` etc.

```
makeMakeModel qFieldNames qMapFunction qConstructor =  -- ["id","name"] 'fromSql 'Person
      LamE [ListP (map VarP qFieldNames)]              -- \ [id,name]
           $ foldl AppE (ConE qConstructor)            -- Person  
                        [AppE (VarE qMapFunction) (VarE name)|name <- qFieldNames]
                                                       -- $ id $ name

makeModel fieldNames mapFunction constructor = do
   names <- mapM newName fieldNames
   return $ makeMakeModel names mapFunction constructor
```

In action in `ghci -XTemplateHaskell`:

```
*Main> runQ $ makeModel ["id","name"] 'fromSql 'Person
LamE [ListP [VarP id_0,VarP name_1]] (AppE (AppE (ConE Main.Person) (AppE (VarE Main.fromSql) (VarE id_0))) (AppE (VarE Main.fromSql) (VarE name_1)))

*Main> $(makeModel ["id","name"] 'fromSql 'Person) ["1234","James"]
Person 1234 "James"
```

Notice how the identifiers we made with `newName` have got serial numbers to make them unique, whereas the ones we passed in with a dash in front, `'fromSql` and `'Person` are preserved as their actual definitions.

---

If you'd rather not use a lambda expression, you can use

```
runQ [d| makeModel [id,name] = Person (fromSql id) (fromSql name) |]
```

as your starting point - `[d| ... |]` is for function definitions.

Comment: See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10653507/haskell-convert-list-to-data/10654675#10654675) for another example.

Comment: Thank you AndrewC! That helps a lot.